# Combine two Eclipse projects from different branches (same repo) into one parent project with sub-projects

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, git, egit

**TLDR**: I am trying to combine 2 git branches into one (which also means that I will be combining two java projects into one)- but do not want the branches/projects to merge. Rather I want the new combined branch to have 2 Java sub-projects into one parent project, if that is possible.
Backstory: Initially I wrote a simple SpringMVC webapp and pushed it to a Github repository through Eclipse (EGit). After a while the *requirements* changed; I was required to split my webapp- the backend and frontend layers into two different projects. The backend needed to be converted to a SpringBoot app, while frontend remains in a Spring app. To accomplish this, I created two branches out of `master`(let's refer to them as `front_end` and `back_end`) in a haste, and made the appropriate changes using two different Eclipse workspace(s).
Flash forward to now- I basically have two projects with the same name, but completely different configurations  (namely `.settings`, `.classpath`, `gitignore`, `.project`) and packages due to differences between SpringMVC and SpringBoot. These projects are currently residing on 2 branches-`front_end` and `back_end`.
My goal is to merge the two projects into one parent project, but can't quite figure out how to do it. Looking for suggestions preferably using EGit, but can also use git bash if push comes to shove.

Comment: Start with one branch, rename the project (or if it is not in a subfolder, move it into a subfolder) and merge the other branch.

Comment: @howlger when I try to move everything in a folder, Eclipse doesn't like it- especially when I move .project in the new folder

Comment: To move a project do the following: in Eclipse delete the project without deleting its content, outside of Eclipse move the project and in Eclipse open it again (_File > Open Projects from File System..._).

Comment: I have been trying to mess around with that for a bit now. Going down that route breaks my Maven connection to the project, jars connect to the parent folder, so my class imports in the new child folder are basically unrecognizable @howlger